# GCP: Can I have several IP subnets on the interface?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, terraform, ip-aliasing

Can I have 2 subnets on the interface of VM in Google Cloud Platform ?

For example:

I have VPC `vpc1` and it have 2 subnets: `subnet1 - 10.1.1.0/24` and `subnet2 - 192.168.1.0/24`

Can I assign to interface `eth1` of VM `bastion` 2 IP addresses  `10.1.1.10` and `192.168.1.10` ?
It is known as IP aliasing and can be done by commands

```
ip addr add 10.1.1.10/24 dev eth1
ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth1
```

I aim to to have access to both subnets from one interface.
If it is possible it will be great to have terraform example.

Thanks

ps: I do not want add several interfaces due to GCP interface-vcpu quota.

[image]

Comment: The documented interface maximum for most instance types is at least two. What limitation in the documentation is causing you problems?   https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces

Comment: Without proper IP aliasing (2+ subnets on the interface) I need 3 interfaces for my bastion host:
ie: WAN, LAN1, LAN2
According to https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#max-interfaces I need run VM with 4 vcpu (even number of vcpus) and it is too expensive for me :(

Comment: Please include a diagram of what you want to accomplish. GCP's firewall is capable of rules targeting instances regardless of subnet or CIDR range. You need firewall rules to deny the system-generated subnet routes anyway.

Comment: I need 3 networks: 1 for WAN and 2 for LAN
This diagram with 3 interfaces: https://i.imgur.com/q2P569l.png 
with vcpu-interfaces limitation.
so I want to share LAN1 and LAN2 on eth1:
https://i.imgur.com/WbQgEuc.png
it is easily can be done with:
```
ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth1;
ip addr add 10.1.1.2/24 dev eth1
```
on linux. but not in GCP reality

Answer (score 0):

[Alias IP ranges](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip) are supported on GCP on the default NIC and here is [how you can apply](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-alias-ip-ranges) them.

However you will not be able to use multiple subnets on the same NIC unless you have multiple NICs.

Comment: As I understand it is incorrect. 
Mentioned IP aliases can be inside *one* subnet.
But I need several subnets on the interface.

Comment: That's correct, I edited my answer to reflect the subnets limitation. For your use case I suggest to make use of containers that would be serving traffic from the 192 subnet as proper use of GCP IP Aliasing.

Comment: You do not understand the question. Please re-read it.
I need to share `eth1` with 2 subnetworks:
https://i.imgur.com/WbQgEuc.png

Answer (score 0):

The network interface can't be "shared", you can use Alias IP with one or more interfaces (your case being only one), setting a max of 10 Alias per interface, this is describe in the [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-alias-ip-ranges#vm-instance-commands).

As commented on the doc, you can run:

```
gcloud compute instances network-interfaces update [INSTANCE_NAME] \
    --zone [ZONE] \
    [--network-interface [NETWORK_INTERFACE]; default="nic0"]
    --aliases "[RANGE_NAME]:[RANGE_CIDR];[[RANGE_NAME]:[RANGE_CIDR],...]"
```

to update an existing instance and add a new Alias IP from another subnet.

Comment: As I understand GCP "Alias IP" - it is like "add route for a sub-subnet" via the VM, is not it ? If so - that is can't help me.

Comment: You can't share a NIC, The only two ways are setting a second NIC, or using IP Alias, (this is not the best practice but, is the only thing available if you don't want to add a new NIC) In both option, you will need to do the route manually.